divide frame horizontally and center images independently in the two minipage environments
I was working on a frame where I intend to show two images with the bottom one progressively changing at each slide. I've done so with \minipage and for the first image I have no issues.
However, the second image which changes over different slides gets shifted horizontally after each slide change, little by little. The effect is not very noticeable but is there nonetheless.
This seems to be tied to my use of \tikzpicture to highlight some steps in the first image and relate them to the second one; however, if that's the case I'm not sure how to fix this... below, a MWE. Thanks in advance!
P.S. I don't have this problem with the first image, but for the second one I wish to have it centered in the page and, eventually, be able to move it horizontally to align it to a specific feature of the first if possible
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\only<1-7>{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics<1->[height=.35\textheight]{example-image-golden}};
        \draw<3>[red!50,ultra thick] (.82,1.745) rectangle (.2135\textheight,.65);
        \draw<4>[red!50,ultra thick] (2.15,1.68) rectangle (.35\textheight,.65);
        \draw<5>[red!50,ultra thick] (3.48,1.745) rectangle (.503\textheight,.65);
        \draw<6>[red!50,ultra thick] (4.81,1.68) rectangle (.65\textheight,.65);
        \draw<7>[red!50,ultra thick] (6.13,1.68) rectangle (.8\textheight,.65);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\only<1>{
\tikz[overlay, remember picture,
    shift=(current page.south west),
    x=(current page.south east), y=(current page.north west),
  ]{
    \node[align=right] at (.73,.4) {\tiny\textit{Adapted from: \dots}};
}
}

\only<2-7>{
\tikz[overlay, remember picture,
    shift=(current page.south west),
    x=(current page.south east), y=(current page.north west),
  ]{
    \node[align=right] at (.73,.48) {\tiny\textit{Adapted from: \dots}};
}
}

\includegraphics<8>[height=.35\textheight]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}

\vfill

\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics<2>[height=.35\textheight]{example-image}
    \includegraphics<3>[height=.35\textheight]{example-image}
    \includegraphics<4>[height=.35\textheight]{example-image}
    \includegraphics<5>[height=.35\textheight]{example-image}
    \includegraphics<6>[height=.35\textheight]{example-image}
    \includegraphics<7>[height=.35\textheight]{example-image}
    \includegraphics<8>[height=.35\textheight]{example-image}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


You are adding spaces after every line. Use \includegraphics<6>[height=.35\textheight]{example-image}% to avoid the additional space

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz indeed, thanks a lot. I completely missed that, think about I was playing out with \hspace to move around those images to get them aligned to the one on top and even realized that they were getting pushed more and more...

A MWE for this question would have been \documentclass{beamer} \begin{document} \begin{frame} \centering     \includegraphics<1>[height=.35\textheight]{example-image-a}     \includegraphics<2>[height=.35\textheight]{example-image-b} \end{frame} \end{document}
